# What does it mean when Mathematica returns a zero "eigenvector"?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

For example, I ask Mathematica to compute the eigenvectors of $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 4 & 5 
 \end{array} \right) $
and it returns 
{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}. What does this mean?

Comment: It means what the ref guide documentation for Eigenvectors says it means, under Details and Options (fifth bullet item).

Comment: sammy, as mentioned, your matrix only has 3 independent eigenvectors, so the list would be padded with $0$ vectors at its end. However, something is not quite right here: what you show is not what `Eigenvectors` returns for your matrix, and the zero padding would only be added at the end of the list, not in the middle. Can you show us the exact code you used, rather than LaTeX expressions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice the $2\times2$ block in the upper left portion of your matrix. This is what is known as a *Jordan block*. Jordan blocks are well-known to be *defective*; that is, they do not have a complete set of eigenvectors.

```
Eigenvectors[{{1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
   {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Since *Mathematica* is unable to yield a complete eigenvector set, it pads the list of eigenvectors with an appropriate number of $\mathbf 0$ vectors so that $n$ vectors are still returned.

In your case, you have the direct sum of a Jordan block and an ordinary matrix, and the defectiveness of this matrix is inherited from the Jordan block. That's why only three linearly independent vectors are returned, in addition to the padding.